# Is there a way to move row to the selected row in UITableView

Tags: iphone

I hope to know if there is a way to move row to the selected row in UITableView.

for example, row are:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

only 3 rows are visible,

I hope to move row directly to 7

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scrollToRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Should also mention that depending on where/when you need to call this, might have to first call [tableView reloadData].  Another thing is that row indexes are zero-based so to go to your row "7", you would actually have to set indexPathForRow to 6.

Comment: If you are getting an error if you load this with -(void)viewDidLoad, it may be because the tableview is not loaded yet. 

I used a delay and it worked perfectly.